# App in not working on android[ Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111) ] address = localhost, port = 51034

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, flutter, mongoose

- i'm trying to make an app with simple signin/singup functionality
  using flutter and nodejs.
- in postman it can send request
- i run it on chrome it work perfectly but not working in android emmulator(and physical device).

> then "i found out that i have to make change with local host" but don't know what...

might be very begginer question

main.dart

```
import 'package:frontend/signin.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Signin(),
  ));
}
```

signin.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:frontend/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:frontend/signup.dart';
import 'package:frontend/user.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Signin extends StatefulWidget {
  Signin({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Signin> createState() => _SigninState();
}

class _SigninState extends State<Signin> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  Future save() async {
    var res = await http.post(
      "http://localhost:8080/signin",
      // "http://10.0.2.2/signin",
      headers: <String, String>{
        "Context-Type": 'application.json;charSet=UTF-8'
      },
      body: <String, String>{
        'email': user.email,
        'password': user.password,
      },
    );
    print(res.body);
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dashboard()),
    );
  }

  User user = User('', '');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          
          children: [
            Positioned(
                top: 0,
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'images/top.svg',
                  width: 400,
                  height: 150,
                )),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 150,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Signin',
                      style: GoogleFonts.pacifico(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 50,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 25,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: TextEditingController(text: user.email),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          user.email = value;
                        },
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Enter Something';
                          } else if (RegExp(
                                  r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                              .hasMatch(value)) {
                            return null;
                          } else {
                            return 'Enter Valid Email';
                          }
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Enter Email",
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                          focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: TextEditingController(text: user.email),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          user.email = value;
                        },
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Enter Something';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Enter Password",
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                          focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 400,
                        child: FlatButton(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              save();
                            } else {
                              print("NOT OK");
                            }
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            "SIGNIN",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(65, 20, 0, 0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            const Text(
                              "not have account ? ",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => Signup()));
                              },
                              child: const Text(
                                "Signup",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

user.dart

```
class User {
  String email;
  String password;
  User(this.email, this.password);
}
```

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 8080 || process.env.PORT;
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", {
// mongoose.connect("mongodb://10.0.2.2:27017/mydb", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/", require("./routes/user.route"));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("port is running on " + port);
});
```

thankyou:)

Comment: You cannot access localhost:8080 from your app because localhost is the Android device when the app is running. You must specify the IP address of the machine where the server is running.

Answer (score 0):

try checking your uri. instead of local host write your ip address